# FFMPEG - Convert DTS-Audio to AC3 - But Keep Original Video and Audio Files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

i am having trouble to understand the documentation on FFMPEG-Website

Can you please help me out?

> So far i got an working command for converting the DTS to AC3 but overwrite the original DTS

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i File.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640k File.mkv
```

Comment: What do you mean "Keep Original Video and Audio Files"? The first `-i` `File.mkv` is the input file, and the last `File.mkv` is the output file name. Give the file a different name...

Comment: i just renamed because i dont want to show off what i am converting here ^^, i am aware to rename output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997597/ffmpeg-convert-dts-audio-to-ac3-but-keep-original-video-and-audio-files

Comment: Got my answer on stackoverflow, thanks although